# Pull back of curvature tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

We can define $(1,3)$ curvature tensor on Riemannian manifold $M$,which is given by $$R(X,Y)Z = \nabla_X\nabla_YZ - \nabla_Y\nabla_XZ -\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$$

We can see that $R(X,Y)Z$ depends on the value of $X,Y,Z$ in a neighborhood correct? Which means $(R(X,Y)Z )|_{U} = R(X|_U,Y|_U)Z_U$.

After that we can define a $(0,4)$ curvature tensor as $$R_m(X,Y,Z,W) = \langle R(X,Y)Z,W\rangle_g \tag{*}$$

What confuse me is that how to make sense of pull back under some smooth map which is given by $$\varphi^*R_m(X,Y,Z,W) = R_m(d\varphi(X),...,d\varphi(W))\circ\varphi$$

But we can't directly substitute it into RHS of (*) correct?Since $d\varphi(X)$ even need not to be a well defined vector field Hence $R(d\varphi(X),d\varphi(Y))d\varphi(Z)$ makes no sense correct?

1. If $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism, can we substitude it into RHS as $$\langle R(d\varphi(X),d\varphi(Y))d\varphi(Z),d\varphi(W)\rangle_g\circ \varphi = \varphi^*R_m(X,Y,Z,W) $$?
2. There is another question which confuses me is that the LHS of (*) depend only on $X,Y,Z,W$ at point $p$ , if we want to evaluate at this point,while the RHS of (*) the $R(X,Y)Z$ depend on the neighborhood of $X,Y,Z$ which confuses me

Comment: The Riemann tensor depends on the values of $X, Y, Z, W$ only at a given point; you don't need to look at a whole neighborhood. Therefore the pullback can be defined as $\phi^* R_m(X, Y, Z, W)|_p = (R_m)_{\phi(p)}(d\phi_p(X), \ldots)$. To calculate this, you could extend $d\phi_p(X)$ (and the others) to arbitrary vector fields on a neighborhood of $\phi(p)$. Again, though, $(R_m)_{\phi(p)}(d\phi_p(X), \ldots)$ only depends on the values of each vector field at the point $\phi(p)$, which is well-defined.

Comment: the question is RHS of (*) the $R(X,Y)Z$ need to eat a vector field, Do $R(X,Y)Z$ independent of choice of extension ? In an other works $R(X,Y)Z$ at point $p$ only depend on $X,Y,Z$ at $p$? @Chris

Comment: It is independent of the choice of extension, yes. @yili

Comment: @Arctic Char ,thank you I got it, vector field $\nabla_X\nabla_YZ$ depend on the $X,Y,Z$ in a neiborhood of $p$ since it's not a tensor, but $R(X,Y)Z$ only depend on the value of $X_p,Y_p,Z_p$ correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. ${}{}{}$